# Odoo, Add a new field into stock picking

Tags: python, odoo

I was trying to add a new field into a `move_lines` in model `stock.picking` and of course, I was inherit the model `stock.picking`. was try like this :

```
<xpath expr="//form/notebook/page/field[@name='move_lines']/form/field[@name='state']" position="after">
    <field name="add_new_field"/>
</xpath>
```

But I always get error :

```
Element '<xpath expr="//form/notebook/page/field[@name='move_lines']/form/field[@name='state']">' cannot be located in parent view
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_lines` is defined like this:

```
<field name="move_lines" string="Stock Move" context="{'address_in_id': partner_id, 'form_view_ref':'stock.view_move_picking_form', 'tree_view_ref':'stock.view_move_picking_tree', 'picking_type': 'internal'}" options='{"reload_on_button": true}'/>
```

And you can see in the context the value of `tree_view_ref` wich we need here.

So if you want to add your field to the tree view try this:

```
<record id="view_move_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name"> view.move.tree.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">stock.move</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_move_picking_tree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='state']" position="after">
                <field name="add_new_field"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because its not able to locate the path.

Simply putting the code below as the xpath should work:

```
<xpath="//field[@name='move_lines']/form//field[@name='state']" position="after">
```